# Bluemix cf push now requires app be deleted before updating occurs

Tags: cloud, push, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Recent attempt to update a node.js app on Bluemix using:

```
cf push piedemo
```

resulted in the following error:

```
Using route piedemo.mybluemix.net
Binding piedemo.mybluemix.net to piedemo...
FAILED
The route piedemo.mybluemix.net is already in use.
TIP: Change the hostname with -n HOSTNAME 
or use --random-route to generate a new route and then push again.
```

---

Work around:
Stopped and deleted the app from Bluemix then re-issued the `cf push` command.

This appears to be a recent change to CF in Bluemix.  In the past one could push an update to an app without having to delete the original before using the `cf push` command.

Anyone has suggestions as to what parameter might help to avoid having to delete the app before using the `cf push` command?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to stop or delete the app before pushing it again.

Make sure you are logged in (`cf login`) to the same organization and space your application was originally deployed. You could see the error you are getting if you try to deploy it to a different organization or space.